# Concatenate 2 columns laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to concatenate 2 columns and researched how to do it but I don't know where the error is, it says column not found, this is my query

```
public function obtenerCargo() {
        if ($this->rcargo_id == null) {
            $this->listCargo = recepcionCargo::select(
               'recepcion_cargo.id',
                'recepcion_cargo.rcargo_id',
                'recepcion_cargo.no_factura',
                'cargo_id.cargo_id',
                'recepcion_cargo.porcentaje',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_minimo',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_devolucion',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_reparacion',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_almacenaje',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_visita',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_traslados',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_fletes',
                'recepcion_cargo.total',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_porcentaje',
                'recepcion_cargo.total_sp',
                DB::raw("CONCAT(recepcion_cargo.total,' ',recepcion_cargo.total_sp) AS TOTAL",'recepcion_cargo.id'))
               ->pluck('TOTAL', 'recepcion_cargo.id')
                ->join('cargo_id', 'cargo_id.id', '=', 'recepcion_cargo.car_id')->get();
        } else {
            $this->listCargo = recepcionCargo::select(
                'recepcion_cargo.id',
                'recepcion_cargo.rcargo_id',
                'recepcion_cargo.no_factura',
                'cargo_id.cargo_id',
                'recepcion_cargo.porcentaje',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_minimo',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_devolucion',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_reparacion',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_almacenaje',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_visita',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_traslados',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_fletes',
                'recepcion_cargo.total',
                'recepcion_cargo.cargo_porcentaje',
                'recepcion_cargo.total_sp',
                DB::raw("CONCAT(recepcion_cargo.total,' ',recepcion_cargo.total_sp) AS TOTAL",'recepcion_cargo.id')
            )
         ->pluck('TOTAL', 'recepcion_cargo.rcargo_id')
                ->join('cargo_id', 'cargo_id.id', '=', 'recepcion_cargo.car_id')
                ->where('recepcion_cargo.rcargo_id', '=', $this->rcargo_id)->get();
        }
    }
```

I am using my model and db:raw with pluck according to this it should work but it does not, in my view a table is displayed and it is not convenient to have 2 total fields so it is better for me to use concat

Answer (score 0):

What is happening in your queries is:

1. You are selecting a lot of columns from a table, including one that belongs to another table and a `DB::raw` statement
2. You are performing the query and extracting the fields `TOTAL` and `recepcion_cargo.id` (that is what `pluck` does, it first performs the query, then extracts the results, so at this point your query will fall)
3. You are joining a `Illuminate\Support\Collection` to another table

I would recommend a couple actions:

1. First, you should join before executing the query (that is, before calling `pluck`
2. Second, to improve the performance, only select the columns that you are going to use

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: I put the join before the pluck and I got very few arguments to work I don't know what it could be

Comment: What pluck does is to only extract the keys that you pass as arguments, maybe you want to use ->get() instead to retrieve all the columns